# Why is my loops for reading into Vector <vector <string> > not working? Linux C++ 

Tags: c++, loops, vector, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to read in a file that only have one column, and write it out to terminal in 3 columns. I have decided to read the one column into separate `vector<string>`. Then put the `vector string` into one `vector<vector <string> >`, before writing out to terminal.

I know it is suppose to be a roster for chores in a flat, hence i know i can split the file by read 15 rows, before i start to read into another vector. However, the number of duties/chores can be changed by the manager, hence i don't know how many `vector<string>` i will need, so i can't just have a set number of `vector<strings>` pre-declared.

The .dat file is in the form of

```
Duty1
P1
P1
P1
...

Duty2
P2
P2
P2
...

Duty3
P3
P3
P3
...
*
```

**This is what i want it to look like**

```
Duty1   Duty2   Duty3
P1      P2      P3
P1      P2      P3
P1      P2      P3
```

**This is how it looks like now**

```
Duty1      Duty1     Duty1
    P1        P1        P1
    P1        P1        P1
    P1        P1        P1
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me spot my mistake

**Here's my code for importing the file.**

```
void DutyManagement::importFlatDuties(){

        ifstream fin1(dutyFile.c_str());

        if( !fin1 ){                                        
            cout << "Unable to find file: " << dutyFile<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        else{

            vector <string> temptVec;
            string tempString;

            flatDutyRoster.clear();                                 

            while(true){

                for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
                fin1 >> tempString;                                     

                   if (tempString == "*"){
                    fin1.close();
                    return;
                   }

                   temptVec.push_back(tempString);                          
                  }

                flatDutyRoster.push_back(temptVec);             
             }              
        }           
}
```

**And here is my code for displaying it to terminal**

```
void DutyManagement::displayDuty(){
    importFlatDuties();

    for (int i=0; i<14; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<flatDutyRoster.size(); j++){
            if (i == 0){
                cout<<setw(10)<<"Duty "<<j+1<<": "<<setw(10)<<flatDutyRoster[j].at(i);
            }
            else{
                cout<<setw(23)<<flatDutyRoster[j].at(i);    
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

I'm almost certain it's just a typo somewhere, but after carefully combing through for several times, i was unable to spot it. It's my first time trying to work with a vector inside a vector. Perhaps I miss understood something? I don't know

Any help would be much appreciated. Either you know what's wrong, or if you've a better way of achieving the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `temptVec.clear()` somewhere.

Comment: OF COURSE!! how could i have missed that!

Edit: And do you know how to format it, so that the output aligns at the beginning of the word, instead of the end?

Comment: Specifically, after the call to `flatDutyRoster.push_back(temptVec)`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I somehow just assumed it would over-write it. So silly of me. I'll be more careful next time.